# Web service interacting with C/C++ hardware interface

Tags: c++, c

I am about to build a web application that is supposed to interact with some C and C++ tools (peripheral hardware access / special data converters). There will be little to none database access by the web app. Pages are mostly filled with content from the C++ data converters.

I am not sure which webserver to pick. I would preferably use JEE/Tomcat because I've done a lot with it in previous projects, knowing that the JVM has some overhead which I would like to avoid.

Rails (which I know a little as well) is not the right choice on my opinion, because it is focused on CRUD applications which this definitely isn't.

I think so far, PHP on apache2 would be the best pick followed by JEE, but

I would like to know if somebody has any other web server / language to suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you look at one of the Python frameworks such as Django or, probably better yet Flask.

- Probably easier to code & maintain than PHP
- Flask in particular is a **micro** framework
- Python can interface really well with C/C++